# converting simple javascript code to c#

Tags: javascript, c#

yesterday i have asked a question here. and the solution is simple using javascript and html

a while ago what im planning is to manipulate the html to do the task in javascript
but i changed my mind, i rewrite the javascript code to c#

here is the input

```
<Abstract>
    <Heading>Abstract</Heading>
    <Para TextBreak="No" >Some paragraph <Emphasis Type="Italic">q</Emphasis><Emphasis Type="Bold">Bold</Emphasis><Emphasis Type="Underline">Underline</Emphasis> </Para>

</Abstract>
```

but the problem is the output on my c# is wrong?

what's wrong with the code i translate?

here is the javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
textval = $('textarea').val();
textnewval = textval.replace('Para TextBreak="No"', 'p').replace('/Para', '/p'); 

  if(textnewval.indexOf('Italic') >= 0) //If Italic
{
    EmphasisAttr = 'Italic';
  textnewval = textnewval.replace('Emphasis Type="'+EmphasisAttr+'"', 'i').replace('/Emphasis', '/i'); 
}
if(textnewval.indexOf('Bold') >= 0) //If Bold
{
    EmphasisAttr = 'Bold';
  textnewval = textnewval.replace('Emphasis Type="'+EmphasisAttr+'"', 'b').replace('/Emphasis', '/b'); 
}
if(textnewval.indexOf('Underline') >= 0) //If underline
{
    EmphasisAttr = 'Underline';
    textnewval = textnewval.replace('Emphasis Type="'+EmphasisAttr+'"', 'u').replace('/Emphasis', '/u'); 
}


  $('textarea').val(textnewval);
  alert($('textarea').val());
});
    </script>
```

the output of the code above is this

```
  <Abstract>
    <Heading>Abstract</Heading>
    <p >Some paragraph <i>q</i><b>Bold</b><u>Underline</u> </p>

</Abstract>
```

which is correct, and below is my c# code. and the output is wrong

```
string result = null;
string input = textBox.Text;

result = input.Replace("Para TextBreak=\"No\"", "p").ToString().Replace("/Para", "/p");
if (result.IndexOf("Italic") >= 0)
{
    string EmphasisAttr = "Italic";
    result = result.Replace("Emphasis Type=\"" + EmphasisAttr + "\"", "i").ToString().Replace("/Emphasis", "/i");
}
 if (result.IndexOf("Bold") >= 0)
{
    string EmphasisAttr = "Bold";
    result = result.Replace("Emphasis Type=\"" + EmphasisAttr + "\"", "b").ToString().Replace("/Emphasis", "/b");
}
 if (result.IndexOf("Underline") >= 0)
{
    string EmphasisAttr = "Underline";
    result = result.Replace("Emphasis Type=\"" + EmphasisAttr + "\"", "u").ToString().Replace("/Emphasis", "/u");
}
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

output:

```
<Abstract>
    <Heading>Abstract</Heading>
    <p >Some paragraph <i>q</i><b>Bold</i><u>Underline</i> </p>

</Abstract>
```

Comment: javascript on a web page is client side code, c# is server side code - in this sense, they are rarely interchangeable - admittedly I haven't gone through your code to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: i converted the javascript code sir to c# but the output is wrong

Comment: can you also in your post the content of `textval`? This is the base of our investigation

Comment: Before this gets translated into C#, I think it has a logical error in the original JavaScript. It only produces the expected result because it's checking first for italics, then bold, then underline, and that's the order in which they appear in your input. If you rearrange the input then the output will be wrong in JavaScript too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that here

```
result = result.Replace("Emphasis Type=\"" + EmphasisAttr + "\"", "i").ToString()
    .Replace("/Emphasis", "/i");
```

you're replacing every instance of `/emphasis` with `/i`. Not just the first one, all of them. After that there are no instances of `/emphasis` to replace with `/b` or `/u`.

In JavaScript, `.replace` by default replaces only the first instance of the matched string. In .NET it replaces all of them.